# How do I change the color of an empty span tag

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am having trouble with changing the color of an empty span tag that I am using for a hamburger menu.

I have tried a few things although I am very new to coding, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
// JavaScript Document
function toggleSidebar(ref) {
  ref.classList.toggle('active');
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
 body {
 font-family:optima;
}

body, html {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
}
video {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 1;
}
body{
  font-family:"Arial", Serif;
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}


.text {
 z-index: 2;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: optima;
 left: 50px;
 top: 50px;
 font-size: 30px;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 font-weight:300;
 
}
#sidebar {
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:300px;
  height:125vh;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align:center;
  transform-origin:left;
  transform:perspective(1200px) rotateY(90deg);
  transition:all 400ms ease;
 z-index: 5;
}
#sidebar ul li {
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #222222;
  line-height:50px;
}
#sidebar.active {
  transform:perspective(1200px) rotateY(0deg);
}



#toggle-btn {
  position:absolute;
  left:30px;
  top:20px;
  transition:left 200ms linear 0ms,transform 300ms ease 100ms;
}
#toggle-btn.active {
  left:230px;
  transform:rotate(360deg);
}
#toggle-btn span {
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  display:block;
  background:#1a1a1a;
  width:30px;
  height:5px;
  margin:5px 0px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:transform 300ms ease 200ms;
}
#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(1) {
  top:10px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity:0;
}
#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(3) {
  top:-10px;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
span {
 z-index: 2;
 background-color:white;
}
.sidebar {
 color: white;
 position: relative;
 z-index :2;  
 
 
 
}
.list {
 color:white;
 
}
ul {
 list-style:none;
}


}

}
ul li a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
} 
ul li:hover ul li{
 display: block;
}
ul li ul li{
 display: none;
}
#sidebar {
 font-family: optima;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
   <title>Melanie Pullen</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="openvid">
 <video poster="road.jpg" autoplay="true" loop muted> 
  <source src="drive.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  

 </video> 
  <div class="text">MELANIE PULLEN</div>
</div> 

 <div id="sidebar">
 <ul>
  <li><a>WORKS</a></li>
  <li><a>INSTALLATION VIEWS</a></li>
  <li><a>UPCOMING SHOWS</a></li>  
  <li><a>PRESS</a></li>
  <li><a>BOOKS</a></li>
  <li><a>BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
  <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
  
  </ul>
 
 </div>
  <div id="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar(this)">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
  
    <script  src="index.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance
I would also like to know why the x button does not work

Comment: Check what other said about the color change. Concerning the X button not working, it's because it's behind other elements and you need to bring it in the 'foreground' using a z-index value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `background-color` property for color changing :

```js
// JavaScript Document
function toggleSidebar(ref) {
  ref.classList.toggle('active');
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
 body {
 font-family:optima;
}

body, html {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
}
video {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 1;
}
body{
  font-family:"Arial", Serif;
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}


.text {
 z-index: 2;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: optima;
 left: 50px;
 top: 50px;
 font-size: 30px;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 font-weight:300;
 
}
#sidebar {
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:300px;
  height:125vh;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align:center;
  transform-origin:left;
  transform:perspective(1200px) rotateY(90deg);
  transition:all 400ms ease;
 z-index: 5;
}
#sidebar ul li {
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #222222;
  line-height:50px;
}
#sidebar.active {
  transform:perspective(1200px) rotateY(0deg);
}

#sidebar ul span{
    color:red;
}



#toggle-btn {
  position:absolute;
  left:30px;
  top:20px;
  transition:left 200ms linear 0ms,transform 300ms ease 100ms;
}
#toggle-btn.active {
  left:230px;
  transform:rotate(360deg);
}
#toggle-btn span {
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  display:block;
  background-color:red;
  width:30px;
  height:5px;
  margin:5px 0px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:transform 300ms ease 200ms;
}
#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(1) {
  top:10px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity:0;
}
#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(3) {
  top:-10px;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
span {
 z-index: 2;
 background-color:white;
}
.sidebar {
 color: white;
 position: relative;
 z-index :2;  
 
 
 
}
.list {
 color:white;
 
}
ul {
 list-style:none;
}


}

}
ul li a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
} 
ul li:hover ul li{
 display: block;
}
ul li ul li{
 display: none;
}
#sidebar {
 font-family: optima;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
   <title>Melanie Pullen</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="openvid">
 <video poster="road.jpg" autoplay="true" loop muted> 
  <source src="drive.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  

 </video> 
  <div class="text">MELANIE PULLEN</div>
</div> 

 <div id="sidebar">
 <ul>
  <li><a>WORKS</a></li>
  <li><a>INSTALLATION VIEWS</a></li>
  <li><a>UPCOMING SHOWS</a></li>  
  <li><a>PRESS</a></li>
  <li><a>BOOKS</a></li>
  <li><a>BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
  <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
  
  </ul>
 
  </div>
  <div id="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar(this)">
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
</div>
  
    <script  src="index.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `span` CSS rule is overwritten by another rule: `#toggle-btn span` , which also has a background-color defined. Since `#toggle-btn span` has more specifity than just `span` , it will overwrite `span`.

To avoid that, just use the same selector for your custom style:

```
#toggle-btn span {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#toggle-btn > span {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The rule above targets the span children of the parent with `id="toggle-btn"`.

```css
body {
  font-family: optima;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

body {
  font-family: "Arial", Serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: optima;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#sidebar {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 125vh;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(90deg);
  transition: all 400ms ease;
  z-index: 5;
}

#sidebar ul li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#sidebar.active {
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(0deg);
}

#toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  transition: left 200ms linear 0ms, transform 300ms ease 100ms;
}

#toggle-btn.active {
  left: 230px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

#toggle-btn span {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  display: block;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 300ms ease 200ms;
}

#toggle-btn>span {
  background: red !important;
}

#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(3) {
  top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

span {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.list {
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


}

}
ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}
#sidebar {
  font-family: optima;
}
```

```html
<div class="openvid">
  <video poster="road.jpg" autoplay="true" loop muted> 
  <source src="drive.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  

 </video>
  <div class="text">MELANIE PULLEN</div>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a>WORKS</a></li>
    <li><a>INSTALLATION VIEWS</a></li>
    <li><a>UPCOMING SHOWS</a></li>
    <li><a>PRESS</a></li>
    <li><a>BOOKS</a></li>
    <li><a>BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
    <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
<div id="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar(this)">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read more about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

your `span` selector is less specific than `#toggle-btn span`, so this properties of `#toggle-btn span` will overwrite those from `span`.

I changed the `span` selector to `#toggle-btn.active span`, so your hamburger menu will be white when the sidebar is active.

```js
// JavaScript Document
function toggleSidebar(ref) {
  ref.classList.toggle('active');
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  font-family: optima;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

body {
  font-family: "Arial", Serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: optima;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#sidebar {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 125vh;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(90deg);
  transition: all 400ms ease;
  z-index: 5;
}

#sidebar ul li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#sidebar.active {
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(0deg);
}

#toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  transition: left 200ms linear 0ms, transform 300ms ease 100ms;
}

#toggle-btn.active {
  left: 230px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

#toggle-btn span {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  display: block;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 300ms ease 200ms;
}

#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#toggle-btn.active span:nth-child(3) {
  top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#toggle-btn.active span {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.list {
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


}

}
ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}
#sidebar {
  font-family: optima;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" <title>Melanie Pullen</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="openvid">
    <video poster="road.jpg" autoplay="true" loop muted> 
  <source src="drive.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  

 </video>
    <div class="text">MELANIE PULLEN</div>
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li><a>WORKS</a></li>
      <li><a>INSTALLATION VIEWS</a></li>
      <li><a>UPCOMING SHOWS</a></li>
      <li><a>PRESS</a></li>
      <li><a>BOOKS</a></li>
      <li><a>BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
      <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>

    </ul>

  </div>
  <div id="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar(this)">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```